# Swift Add different actions to cells on a UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I don't know where to start, I have a UICollectionView with multiple cells filled with a UIImage. I want each cell/UIImage to do a **different** action on a fingertap. Can someone pinpoint me in the right direction here?

The action that I have is a @IBAction from a UIButton, I know want have that action on a cell in the UICollectionView..

( I Guess I have to do something with the 'let cell = countryCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell' ?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var soundsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    lazy var cv: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
    var cc = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    cc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    cc.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
    cc.delegate = self
    cc.dataSource = self
    cc.backgroundColor = .white
    return cc
    }()
    
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            
            view.addSubview(cv)
            cv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
            cv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            
        }
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
    
}

class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    lazy var centerImageView: UIImageView = {
        var img = UIImageView()
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handler(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        
        img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return img
    }()
    
    @objc private func handler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped tag > ", self.tag)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addSubview(centerImageView)
        centerImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        centerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey Dede did it worked for you?

Comment: Hi elia, thanks for your reply! I'm struggling a bit. I have updated the 'cellForItemAt' method and add this to my soundsCell.swift (UICollectionViewCell class?)

`@IBAction func sound1(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (self.tag == 0) {
          // I am first cell, so act like this.
        }  else if (self.tag == 1) {
          // Second cell blah blah
        }
    }`

But how do I configure each cell differently to do something on a fingertap?
For example image1: print ("i'm button 1")
And image2: print ("I'm button 2")

Again, thanks for your time! Very appreciated

Comment: hey again, use `UITapGestureRecognizer` for `UIImageView` in `UICollectionViewCell`. In tap gesture `#action` function check `self.tag` so you can handle that if `tag == 0` so this is image of first cell. and if `tag == 3` this is 4. cell. Did you mind?

Comment: Well, been trying to understand what you mean the last 48 hours, I'm really trying to get it work and put some own research into it before asking stupid questions here :P . I added this `let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
                tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
                view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)` in my ViewController (viewDidLoad). And a     `@objc func doubleTapped() {
        // do something here
    }`

But I don't understand what you mean with the `self.tag`.. Am I on the right track with the code above? Thanks again Elia!

Comment: hey @Dede, you can assign `UICollectionViewCell` to tag and this tag helps you which cell is which element in inner of the `UICollectionViewCell`. I edit my answer as an example for you

Comment: @elia , I'm getting close now! :) But, when I now RUN the app the screen is all white. But when I randomly click on the screen I see "Tapped tag > 1" or 2 etc. on the console output. So it's working, but I don't see images. I think I deleted some thing of my original code. I updated my code on my first post so you can see what I've got now. Can you see what's missing? Thanks again!! (And sorry for my late reply).

Comment: if you use `img.image = UIImage(named: "1")` line for the code, this line says you must have an image with name `1` . so you must use your own imageNames maybe?

Comment: @elia Ofcourse.. it works..! But.. How do I configure muliple images? Let's say I'm having 10 different images.. :/

Comment: Assume that you have an array `let imageArray = [UIImage(named:"first"),UIImage(named:"second"),UIImage(named:"third"),UIImage(named:"fourth")]`   and in `cellForRow` method you have to call `myCell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]` or how you handle your cell. For my example in answer this should be `cell.centerImageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]`. you have to figure out the ``numberOfCount` must equal `imageArray` count

Comment: @elia I get it, but `cellForRow` ? I don't have any..? Do you mean `cellForItemAt` ?

Comment: yeah, I mean `cellForItemAt` method :)

Comment: Hmmm, getting a Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage'   `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.centerImageView.image = countries[indexPath.row]
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218234/discussion-between-elia-and-dede-schurk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edit as new programmatically example for your problem solution.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    lazy var cv: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical
        
        var cc = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        cc.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        cc.register(CustomCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
        cc.delegate = self
        cc.dataSource = self
        cc.backgroundColor = .white
        return cc
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(cv)
        cv.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        cv.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        cv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        cv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        cell.tag = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 100)
    }
    
    
}


class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    lazy var centerImageView: UIImageView = {
        var img = UIImageView()
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        img.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        img.clipsToBounds = true
        img.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handler(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        
        img.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        
        return img
    }()
    
    @objc private func handler(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        print("tapped tag > ", self.tag)
    }
    
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        
        
        addSubview(centerImageView)
        centerImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        centerImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
        centerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 80).isActive = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: hey @DeDeSchurk did you build it?

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario, I would avoid using buttons on your cells. Instead you should hook into the [didSelectItemAt delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618032-collectionview) and just add the necessary information into a data model:

```
struct Country {
    let imageName: String
    let sound: Sound // You didn't specify what type the sound1 object is but you get the gist
}
```

So your countries array will now contain this new struct instead of just raw Strings:

```
let countries = [
    Country("country1", sound1),
    Country("country2", sound2),
    ...
]
```

Then you can get the exact sound you want to play from the indexPath passed into didSelectItemAt:

```
let sound = self.countries[indexPath.row].sound
sound.play()
```

You'll also need to adjust how you're setting the cell's image in cellForItemAt:

```
let imageName = self.countries[indexPath.row].imageName
cell.countryImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
```